# Why after x number of times Math.random() function gives only one number over and over

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using `useState` in React. After x number of time (15-20) `getRandomNumbers` function does not give random numbers anymore. It gives only one number over and over.

**What am i doing wrong here???**

```
import {useState} from "react";

function App() {

  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState(['1','2','3','4', '5']);
  
  function getRandomNumbers(){
      let result = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
          result.push(numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)]);
      }
      // setting new array in numbers
      setNumbers(numbers => result);
  }
  
  const displayNumbers = numbers.map((no, i) => {
      return (
          <div key={i}>{no}</div>
      );
  });

  return (
          <div>
              {displayNumbers}
              <br/>
              <button type='button' onClick={() => getRandomNumbers()}>Click</button>
          </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is initial value array of string or numbers ? Just askin

Answer (score 2):

you need to take out the range of allowed values

Imagine that after the first click there will be several identical numbers in the array, for example `[1, 1, 1, 5, 3]`
The probability of rolling a `1` is much higher than a `3` or `5`.

solution link
--> https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cache-09xkid?file=/src/App.js

Also post solution here:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const allowedNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

function App() {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState(Array.from(allowedNumbers));

  function getRandomNumbers() {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      result.push(allowedNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedNumbers.length)]);
    }
    // setting new array in numbers
    setNumbers((numbers) => result);
  }

  const displayNumbers = numbers.map((no, i) => {
    return <div key={i}>{no}</div>;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {displayNumbers}
      <br />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => getRandomNumbers()}>
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```